# How to ensure javascript single page application to be executed on single browser tab only

Tags: javascript, tabs, mutex, single-page-application

I am building SPA application is emberjs framework and I need to ensure that the application instance is running only once (on single tab) on same domain.

Analogy of mutex to prevent multiple instances known from desktop application development world.

There are some solution I am considering just now like using localStorage locks or `window.postMessage` or `SharedWorker` but non of them looks bulletproof to me.

Do you have some ideas?

Thanks is advance.

Comment: Why do you need to ensure that?

Comment: Is there a user login involved?

Comment: Because I am receiving asynchronous events from websockets which stores data in various resources or do some actions which requires user attention. e.g when some event is received sound is played and data are stored to indexeddb.  If there would be no concurrency control sound would be played twice and also data would be stored twice.

Comment: A user can open multiple browsers too so you won't be able to do enforce this client-side at all.  You will have to enforce it server-side.  One idea would be to allow only one webSocket connection at a time per logged-in user.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks but multiple browser would be problem only in case of desktop notification or playing the sounds. Whats bothering me more is double storing of data in single browser instance. Also I cannot ensure single websocket connection by design. I am really looking for some client-side only solution to this problem. I have already written Critical Section analogy https://medium.com/medium-eng/wait-dont-touch-that-a211832adc3a but it requires me to use it on many places

Comment: I still don't understand the real problem here.  Are  you storing data client-side in Local Storage? Is that what you're trying to prevent multiple access to?

Comment: Lets say I receive some data in asynchronous event from websocket, which I need to store to indexeddb, when 2 tabs would be opened data will be stored twice. Maybe I forgot to say that websocket server by design multiplexes the messages -> it sends them to all connections related to signed user.  By the way for while there was already answer suggesting using localStorage events and logout user in one tab when same user logs in another - this would work for me. I do not know why but answer disappeared.

Answer (score 1):

I've used `localStorage` to make sure when users log out in one tab it logs them out in other tabs and it's worked quite well.

1. Bind to the `storage` event on the `window` object and use the `event.key`/`event.newValue` keys to determine what action to take. You can also use the `event.url` key to make sure the `storage` event is firing from the correct page. In my code I set a `logged-out` flag if the `url`, `key` and `newValue` data validates.
2. Bind to the `focus` event on the `window` object and check the value of the `logged-out` flag and auto-logout the user if it's set to `true`.

For my purpose I had to initialize the `localStorage` data to "not logged out" on page load because the `storage` event will not fire if you don't actually change the value of the `localStorage` key you're watching. I.e. if the value is `blah` and you set it to `blah`, no event will fire.

This works back to IE 8 too.

For your purpose you could set a `localStorage` key/value when someone logs in and block the page from working if that key/value is already set. Maybe set a timestamp as the value so if someone doesn't properly logout they can get back in after so many seconds. Then set an interval to update the timestamp while the user is logged in.

This is untested, if you go down this road I'd be interested to see how it works for you and what you had to do to make it work.

Comment: How does this prevent the user from opening multiple tabs on the same site?

Comment: @jfriend00 It's not an exact answer, just an explanation that `localStorage` will work cross-tab with a little explanation on how.

Comment: Since it is not obvious to me how to use this to solve the OP's problem, I don't see how it's an answer at all.  If you think this can lead to a solution to the exact problem the OP has, then please describe how to do that.

Comment: The point of an answer is to answer the actual question - otherwise it should be a comment.  If you think your comment leads to an answer, then why don't you put the sequence of events that actually describes an answer to the question in your actual answer.  Since the user can also have multiple browsers open, I don't see how this problem can be solved client-side at all.  It seems to me the only way to enforce one active window per user is server-side.

Comment: Thanks @Jasper   proposed idea will work for me.

By he way `window.postMessage` could be also used to notify other tabs. 

This solution did not came to my mind at all because I was thinking in desktop manner - oposite manner. Forbid the app to open in tab when it is already opened in another tab.